# Creating python function to merge line segments if they are connected using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, vector, line, intersect

I have a polyline shapefile consisting of several line segment features. I want to do a merge operation if the line segment features endpoints are connected, and if the features are disconnected do not merge it. Put it in separate.

So my Logic is -

*fetch the co-ordinates of the vertices from the ROADS feature class & then using Polyline method and Insert Cursor create a new feature which will create a new road having all the co-ordinates; but I am getting an error.*

Here is my code to fetch the co-ordinates & make new polyline

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\Drona_Maps\Desktop\Office Work\Python task\Geodatabase\Road_Geodatabase.gdb\Road_featuredataset\ROAD'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
fc = r'C:\Users\Drona_Maps\Desktop\Office Work\Python task\Geodatabase\Road_Geodatabase.gdb\Road_featuredataset\ROAD'

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ['OID@', 'SHAPE@']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        array1 = row[1].getPart()
        for vertice in range(row[1].pointCount):
            pnt = array1.getObject(0).getObject(vertice)
            listOfCoordinates = [pnt.X,pnt.Y]
            print (listOfCoordinates)


array2 = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(listOfCoordinates)])

spatial_reference = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
singlepart_polyline = arcpy.Polyline(array2, spatial_reference)

cursor.insertRow([singlepart_polyline])
```

The Error I am facing is:

```
[-144.37499999999997, -63.020833332999985]
[-109.54166666699996, -26.812499999999943]
[-109.54166666699996, -26.812499999999943]
[-15.583333332999928, 26.354166667000072]
[-15.583333332999928, 26.354166667000072]
[104.50000000000006, 61.18750000000006]
[112.75000000000011, 64.85416666700007]
[163.16666666700007, 100.14583333300004]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Drona_Maps/Desktop/Office Work/Python task/Initial try/2nd Method.py", line 16, in <module>
    array2 = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(listOfCoordinates)])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 1082, in _init_
    setattr(self, attr, value)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.4\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\_base.py", line 89, in _set
    return setattr(self._arc_object, attr_name, cval(val))
RuntimeError: Point: Input value is not numeric

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am doing this in Pycharm using Python version 2.7 and arcpy module and using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.

Comment: Have you tried exploring the [Dissolve Tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) and the unsplit_lines/multi_part parameters? This tool may do it all for you?

Comment: @Hornbydd Yeah dissolve tool does all the work very easily. But I am looking for some other way from the scratch. Like to extract coordinates of the vertices and then convert into a new polyline with the help of Insert Cursor.

Comment: Shouldnt the array be created from a list of points? You are trying to create one point from a list of coordinates, then pass this to the array. (Im not sure)

Comment: @GeoSharp can you please comment on this.

Comment: Im trying to tell you this (untested): `array2 = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*c) for c in listOfCoordinates])`